# Get HTML Dropdownlist selected item in Razor Webpages

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-webpages

I am having some difficulty figuring out how to return the selected item in my HTML.DropDownList so that upon hitting a submit button, the selected item text will be looked up in my database. Here is what I have:

```
@{
var selectStaff = "Select LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS Name, StaffID  From StaffList ORDER BY LastName";
var data = db.Query(selectStaff);
var items = data.Select(i => new SelectListItem {
    Text = i.Name
  });
}
```

And then in the html..

```
@Html.DropDownList("Select1", items)
```

This works fine, as my dropdownlist is appearing and is populated, but now upon hitting a submit button, I want to be able to search that text of the selected item in my database. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't bind the dropdown to a property on your view model (which would be preferable), you can still get it simply using `Request.Form["Select1"]` in your controller action.

If you mean that you want to be able to get the value while still on the razor page, you need to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (or other javascript) to get the value.

To get the value with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#YourSubmitButtonID").click(function () {
         // Get the value from 'Select1'
         var value = $("#Select1").val();
     });
});
```

To do something with the value, you would have to use an ajax function, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
    data: { valueToQuery: $("#Select1").val() },
    success: function (data) {
       // The data is the result
    }
});
```

On the controller named ControllerName in this example, you'd have the code that queries the database and returns your result.

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string valueToQuery)
{
     // Do your stuff here
    return Json("your result", , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
{
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also found [THIS](https://forums.asp.net/t/1767062.aspx?Html%20DropDownList%20Help%20How%20to%20link%20with%20database%20Razor%20syntax%20) very interesting that May help you out!

You may also try the following Steps if you don't want to use Ajax or Json tactics:

```
var sql = "SELECT ProductId, ProductName FROM Products";
var data = Database.Open("Northwind").Query(sql);
var items = data.Select(i => new SelectListItem {
    Value = i.ProductId.ToString(),
    Text = i.ProductName
});


@Html.DropDownList("productid", items)
```

And Also:

```
var sql = "SELECT ProductId, ProductName FROM Products";
var data = Database.Open("Northwind").Query(sql);

<select name="productid">
@foreach(var row in data){
    <option value="@row.ProductId">@row.ProductName</option>
}
</select>
```